# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'add')

Tags: shopify, slick.js

below is my slider code i got error of can't read property of null reading add kindly do needfull

```
$('.main_images').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  asNavFor: '.thumb_images'
});

$('.thumb_images').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.main_images',
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  vertical: true,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: false,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 481,
      settings: {
        vertical: false,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1

      }
    }
  ]
});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's due to calling init twice. Try below code...

```
$('.thumb_images').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.main_images',
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  vertical: true,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: false,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 481,
      settings: {
        vertical: false,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1

      }
    }
  ]
});
```